# Django makemigrations command generate the same migrations everytime

Tags: django

My project is base on django framework, the makemigrations command not work correctly. The `makemigrations` command generate the same script everytime , but my code has not changed.

I upgraded the django version, but the problem remains.
The `django` is 2.2 now

models.py

```
class BatchUploadRecord(models.Model):

    create_date = models.DateTimeField(_("date created"), auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(_("date updated"), auto_now=True)


    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, related_name='course_batchtemp', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, related_name='lesson_batchtemp', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

migrations

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('courses', '0025_auto_20190130_1634'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='batchuploadrecord',
            name='lesson',
            field=models.ForeignKey(null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='lesson_batchtemp', to='courses.Lesson'),
        ),
    ]
```

Run the `makemigrations` command

```
(rinpoche) ➜  rinpoche_ask_api git:(develop) ✗ ./manage.py makemigrations 
Migrations for 'courses':
  applications/courses/migrations/0027_auto_20190409_1658.py
    - Alter field lesson on batchuploadrecord
(rinpoche) ➜  rinpoche_ask_api git:(develop) ✗ ./manage.py makemigrations 
Migrations for 'courses':
  applications/courses/migrations/0028_auto_20190409_1658.py
    - Alter field lesson on batchuploadrecord
(rinpoche) ➜  rinpoche_ask_api git:(develop) ✗ ./manage.py makemigrations 
Migrations for 'courses':
  applications/courses/migrations/0029_auto_20190409_1658.py
    - Alter field lesson on batchuploadrecord
```

I don't how to fix it.

Comment: can you add other migrations files code also?

Comment: Yes, I create new Model in my models.py,  the `makemigration`  create new migration file contains new model and the `Alter field` duplicate

Answer (score 0):

If you do not worry about database right now, try to remove all migrations and reset them. To do that follow my instructions:

1. `find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "__init__.py" -delete`
2. `find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete`
3. Drop the current database, or delete the `db.sqlite3`
4. Create the initial migrations and generate the db schema.

   `python manage.py makemigrations`

   `python manage.py migrate`

If you are stuck here is whole tutorial to this: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html

Comment: I wish I can do that, but my project is running on production environment for 2 years with DevOps,  I am worried that this will destroy the original deployment process, and there may be unpredictable situations.

Comment: How about doing dump of database ? Then reset whole db as I wrote, make migrations, migrate and upload data to database ?